# Ordenar List em java

Tags: java, lista

Tenho uma `List<Pessoa>` onde os atributos do objeto são: Nome, idade, endereço, etc. Tenho uma Tela onde vou inserindo pessoas nessa lista e gero um relatório, gostaria de exibir esse objeto ordenados por Nome. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pode implementar a interface Comparable e tornar objetos da classe pessoa comparáveis com outros objetos do mesmo tipo:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Pessoa implements Comparable<Pessoa>  {
    private String nome;
    private int idade;
    private String endereco;

    //getters and setters

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pessoa p) {
        return this.getNome().compareTo(p.getNome());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pessoa [nome=" + nome + ", idade=" + idade + ", endereco="
                + endereco + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa();
        p1.setNome("João");
        Pessoa p2 = new Pessoa();
        p2.setNome("Maria");
        Pessoa p3 = new Pessoa();
        p3.setNome("André");
        List<Pessoa> pessoas = new ArrayList();
        pessoas.add(p1);
        pessoas.add(p2);
        pessoas.add(p3);
        Collections.sort(pessoas);
        System.out.println(pessoas);        
    }
}
```

Tornando possível então chamar o método `Collections.sort(pessoas);`.

Resultado:

> [Pessoa [nome=André, idade=0, endereco=null]
>   , Pessoa [nome=João, idade=0, endereco=null]
>   , Pessoa [nome=Maria, idade=0, endereco=null]
>   ]

Comment: Muito Obrigado Math, funcionou, eu tinha tentando usar o `Collections.sort();` porém não sabia que tinha que implementar uma interface

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Pessoa>  pessoas = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();

// setando
Pessoa pessoa;
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
  pessoa = new pessoa();
  pessoa.setNome(...);
  pessoas.add(pessoa);
}

//Ordenando
Collections.sort(pessoas, new Comparator<Pessoa>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Pessoa  pessoa1, Pessoa  pessoa2)
        {

            return  pessoa1.Nome.compareTo(pessoa2.Nome);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Assim eu acho mais fácil ainda:
 - Utilizando Metode Reference do java 8

```
Collections.sort(listaPessoas, Comparator.comparing(Pessoa::getNome));
```

Abraços!!

Answer (score 2):

Imagino que já tenha setado os atributos então vou deixar apenas o método que faz a ordenação:

O compare aceita um `@Override` onde você pode implementar sua ordenação.

Sua classe precisa implementar a interface `Comparator`

```
  private static void ordenaPorNome(List<Pessoa> listaPessoas) {  
        Collections.sort(listaPessoas, new Comparator<Pessoa>() {  
            @Override  
            public int compare(Pessoa p1, Pessoa p2) {  
                return p1.getNome().compareTo(p2.getNome());  
            }  

     });  
    }
```

Comment: Você disse que ele precisa implementar a classe Comparable mas no seu exemplo você implementa a classe Comparator. As duas funcionam, cada uma da sua forma, mas acredito que seria deixar isso mais claro. Além disso, você poderia trocar o `List<Lista>` por `List<Pessoa>`.

Comment: Não me atentei, vou arrumar